# How to create a factory of constants, action creators and reducers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In my application I have a lot of modules that group constants, action creators and reducers in the same file to reduce file fragmentation, and they look like this:

```
    /**
     * Store
     * Products
     */

    import { Api } from './api';

    // Constants

    const REQUEST_PRODUCTS = 'REQUEST_PRODUCTS';
    const RECEIVE_PRODUCTS = 'RECEIVE_PRODUCTS';

    // Action creators

    export function requestProducts() {
        return { type: REQUEST_PRODUCTS };
    }

    export function receiveProducts(json) {
        return {
            type: RECEIVE_PRODUCTS,
            entities: json.results,
            receivedAt: Date.now()
        };
    }

    function fetchProducts() { // Thunk
        return function (dispatch, getState) {
            dispatch(requestProducts());
            return Api.get('/products/')
                .then(json => dispatch(receiveProducts(json)))          
        }
    }

    // Reducer

    export function reducer(state = {
        isFetching: false,
        didInvalidate: false,
        entities: []
    }, action = '') {
        switch (action.type) {
            case REQUEST_PRODUCTS:
                return Object.assign({}, state, {
                    isFetching: true,
                    didInvalidate: false
                });
            case RECEIVE_PRODUCTS:
                return Object.assign({}, state, {
                    isFetching: false,
                    didInvalidate: false,
                    entities: action.entities,
                    lastUpdated: action.receivedAt
                });
            default:
                return state
        }
    }
```

In my store configuration, I then import the reducers like this:

```
    import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
    import { routeReducer } from 'redux-simple-router'

    const rootReducer = combineReducers({
        routing: routeReducer,
        products: require('../modules/products').reducer,
        blah: require('../modules/blah').reducer,
    });

    export default rootReducer;
```

And from the components I import the actions like this:

```
    import { fetchProducts } from '../modules/products';
    dispatch( fetchProducts() );
```

All "store" files are exactly the same except for the constant names and the entity name in the action creator functions. As the commandment says: don't repeat yourself, this is an ideal candidate for refactor, so I'm trying to create a factory I can use to eliminate repetition and still have some degree of customization on each "store". But given my limited Javascript experience, specially on ES6 module syntax, I'm having a hard time coming up with a decent solution.

Any ideas I could try?

Comment: Have you read the Redux [real-world](https://github.com/rackt/redux/tree/master/examples/real-world) example? It solves a lot of these issues, but takes a while to parse through what he's doing.

Comment: @Mike yeah, but he uses the "api middleware" and I really had a hard time to understand the syntax of the example, let alone how it works. I went a simpler route for my app, but I ended with repetition.

Comment: I heard this from one of Harry's ([csswizardry](http://csswizardry.com/)) talks: DRY < the wrong abstraction. Basically, don't worry about repetition to keep your app simple if abstracting it is a huge headache. Code which is clear, not clever.

Comment: Yeah, I try to remember that from time to time too :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have multiple of these things, I'd recommend to make them objects instead of modules. That just makes them easier to manipulate programmatically (than, say, module code), and to store in a data structure as well:

```
const REQUEST_PRODUCTS = 'REQUEST_PRODUCTS';
const RECEIVE_PRODUCTS = 'RECEIVE_PRODUCTS';

export default {
    // Action creators
    requestProducts() {
        return { type: REQUEST_PRODUCTS };
    },
    receiveProducts(json) {
        return {
            type: RECEIVE_PRODUCTS,
            entities: json.results,
            receivedAt: Date.now()
        };
    },
    fetchProducts() { // Thunk
         return (dispatch, getState) => {
            dispatch(this.requestProducts());
            return Api.get('/'+type+'/')
                .then(json => dispatch(this.receiveProducts(json)))          
        }
    },

    // Reducer
    reducer(state = {
        isFetching: false,
        didInvalidate: false,
        entities: []
    }, action = '') {
        switch (action.type) {
            case REQUEST_PRODUCTS:
                return Object.assign({}, state, {
                    isFetching: true,
                    didInvalidate: false
                });
            case RECEIVE_PRODUCTS:
                return Object.assign({}, state, {
                    isFetching: false,
                    didInvalidate: false,
                    entities: action.entities,
                    lastUpdated: action.receivedAt
                });
            default:
                return state
        }
    }
};
```

Well that was simple. But now that we have a *thing* - a JavaScript value, we can very easily wrap it in a function that returns this.

And then all we need to do is to remove the instance-specific parts (in this case, the "products" suffices), and replace them with parameters that are passed to the function:

```
function moduleFactory(type) {
    const REQUEST = 'REQUEST_'+type.toUpperCase();
    const RECEIVE = 'RECEIVE_'+type.toUpperCase();

    return {
        // Action creators
        request() {
            return { type: REQUEST };
        },
        receive(json) {
            return {
                type: RECEIVE,
                entities: json.results,
                receivedAt: Date.now()
            };
        },
        fetch() { // Thunk
            return (dispatch, getState) => {
                dispatch(this.request());
                return Api.get('/'+type+'/')
                    .then(json => dispatch(this.receive(json)))          
            }
        },

        // Reducer
        reducer(state = {
            isFetching: false,
            didInvalidate: false,
            entities: []
        }, action = '') {
            switch (action.type) {
                case REQUEST:
                    return Object.assign({}, state, {
                        isFetching: true,
                        didInvalidate: false
                    });
                case RECEIVE:
                    return Object.assign({}, state, {
                        isFetching: false,
                        didInvalidate: false,
                        entities: action.entities,
                        lastUpdated: action.receivedAt
                    });
                default:
                    return state
            }
        }
    };
}
```

And you're done! Now you can of course optimise this, e.g. by sharing methods that don't rely on the type between multiple modules, but that's not substantial.

```
import moduleFactory from '…';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    routing: routeReducer,
    products: moduleFactory('products').reducer,
    blah: moduleFactory('blah').reducer,
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the original example is a bit contrived. In an actual Redux application, most of these functions exists in separate modules themselves, so wrapping the entire thing in an object is not a good idea.

Comment: @Mike: Well if all of these modules look like each other, then they shouldn't be separate modules, that's what I'm trying to say. Rather there should be only one module with the factory function that creates "module objects". Of course, depending on the amount of "customisation" each module needs, it might still go in an extra file, but only call the factory function there.

Comment: The original example it's a lot similar to what I'm doing in the real application, I tried to keep everything in the same module following [this proposal](https://github.com/erikras/ducks-modular-redux) which made sense to me at the time.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, I ended up implementing something similar to this! I've been a long time developing JS and I still feel like a newbie.

Answer (score 4):

Reducer composition is key here. Create a reducer by abstracting the repeating parts of the code. We return a reducer function similar to those already being used for `products`, etc; however, we pass a `key` (String) through so that at the root of our state we can track and update `products`, `blah`, etc. If you are unfamiliar with spread operaters it is similar to doing `Object.assign({}, state, {state[key]: {updates}});`.

```
function entities (key) {
  return function entitiesByKey (state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case REQUEST:
        return {
          ...state,
          state[key]: {
            isFetching: true
          }
        };
      case RECEIVE:
        return {
          ...state,
          state[key]: {
            entities
          }
        };
    }
  }
}
```

Then figure out how to use it with your current root reducer:

```
combineReducers({
  products: entities('products'),
  blah: entities('blah')
});
```

This should result in a state tree similar to this (an incomplete example):

```
{
  products: {
    isFetching: false,
    entities: {}
  },
  blah: {}
}
```

I haven't tested this code at all, but the concept is there.

As far as the real-world example and the API middleware it is actually quite simple. He is passing an object (`[CALL_API]`) through action creators with API information (url, constants, etc.). When it hits the middleware he extracts the `[CALL_API]` object and initializes a literal API call (using `fetch()`) and then properly reformats the action object based on the responses. `[CALL_API]` looks confusing,  but it's the syntax for using a `Symbol()` as an object key:

```
export const MY_SYMBOL = Symbol('My Symbol');

{
  [MY_SYMBOL]: {
    prop: "value"
  }
}
```

The reason for this is because Symbols are unique values so there is no way to override `[CALL_API]` as if it were a string.

Comment: I'm honestly not quite sure I remember what combination of `{...state, state[key]}` worked for me. I switched to doing `{...state, entities[key]}` at some point. You'll have to play around with it, but it does work.

Comment: Thanks for this solution! I ended up using a variation of @Bergi 's because it was more in line to what I wanted to do and I was half-way there, but I'll keep in mind this technique of reducer composition as my app grows! :)